# C Program executing differently from shell

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to read this input as characters into memory in c in a 2 dimensional array.

```
00P015
00P116
030000
06P0ZZ
030005
06P1ZZ
04P0ZZ
26P1ZZ
3412ZZ
030010
06P0ZZ
99ZZZZ
030010
06P1ZZ
99ZZZZ
ZZ0000
ZZ0010
```

My code is

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int pr;
int value;
/*These are variables representing the VM itself*/

char IR[6] ;
short int PC = 0 ;

int P0 ;                                                                //these are the pointer registers
int P1 ;
int P2 ;
int P3 ;

int R0 ; //GP regs
int R1 ;
int R2 ;
int R3 ;

int ACC ;
char PSW[2];
char memory [100][6]  ;                                                 //this is the program memory for first program
short int opcode ;                                                      //nice to know what we are doing
int program_line = 0 ;


int fp ;
int i ;
int q = -1;                                                                  //Used to iterate through memory to execute program
int TrueFalse;                                                          //True / False value for check statements, 1 implies true, 0 implies false
int halt = 0;
int address;


char input_line [7] ;

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{                                                                       //Read file into VM
    fp = open("C:\\Users\\Whiskey Golf\\ClionProjects\\untitled\\program.txt", O_RDONLY) ;
    printf("Open is %d\n", fp) ;                                        //always check the return value.

    if (fp < 0)                                                         //error in read
    {printf("Could not open file\n");
        exit(0) ;
    }
                                                                        //read in the first line of the program
    int charRead = read (fp, input_line, 8 ) ;                          //returns number of characters read`
    printf("\n*******************************\n");
    printf("* Reading Program Into Memory *\n");
    printf("*******************************\n");
    while (1)
    { if (charRead <= 0)                                                //indicates end of file or error
            break ;                                                     //breaks out of infinite loop

        for (i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)                                        //If we get here must have correctly read in a line of program code.
            memory[program_line][i] = input_line[i] ;                   //copy from input line into program memory

        printf("Program Line %d: ", program_line) ;                     //printing out program line for debugging purposes
        for(i = 0; i <  6; i++)
            printf("%c", memory[program_line][i]) ;
        printf("\n") ;

        opcode = (memory[program_line][0] -48) *10 ;                    //Get opcode, print out opcode to console
        opcode += (memory[program_line][1] -48) ;

        printf("Opcode is %d\n", opcode) ;

        charRead = read (fp, input_line, 8) ;                           //read in next line of code

        if(input_line[0] == 'Z')                                        //if the firat character is a 'Z' then you are reading data.
            break ;                                                     //No more program code so break out of loop

        program_line++ ;                                                //now at a new line in the prog
        printf("%n");
    }
```

The issue I am having is that when I run the program in the IDE I wrote it in, Clion, my output is correct, I get

```
Program Line 0: 00P015
Opcode is 0
Program Line 1: 00P116
Opcode is 0
Program Line 2: 030000
Opcode is 3
Program Line 3: 06P0ZZ
Opcode is 6
```

But when I run the code via a shell via gcc compilation then ./a.out execution, the output I get is

```
Program Line 0: 00P015
Opcode is 0
Program Line 1: 16
Opcode is -528
Program Line 2: 00
Opcode is -528
Program Line 3: ZZ
Opcode is-528
```

I have been trying to debug this issue for a while now, and I can not get it to work correctly when I do it through the shell, which is the way I need to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know that C strings have an additional `'\0'` char to signal the end of the string?

Comment: Do not use magical numbers in your code! Why use `48`, if you apparently mean `'0'`?

Comment: Yes, it is accounted for, and my code works when I run it via Clion but not when I do via gcc compilation.

Comment: I use 48 to convert the char to it's equivalent integer.

Comment: Your code should never work, or maybe sometimes. That's how undefined behavior is, you allocate 6 bytes for a 7 bytes string of 6 chracters, remember `'\0'` at the end!.

Comment: Yes and `'0'` is equal to `48` it would make more sense to write `x - '0'`, since the numbers are consecutive in ascii too so it works as conversion.

Comment: What is a Clion? And if it does not run properly when compiled with gcc, it also does not work otherwise (unless you really found a compiler bug). It just might **seem** to work.

Comment: I allocate 7. char input_line [7] ;

Comment: And you read `8`!!!! Also, no reason to use global variables in this code.

Comment: When I change it out [8] I get virtually no change in my code.

Comment: Use valgrind. And you seem not to have debugged properly. What did you try in the debugger? Single step and inspect the values read.

Comment: @Olaf, that is a tool for happy people who use a really nice OS.

Comment: "When I change it out [8] I get virtually no change in my code." So try to allocate none at all. Perhaps the data read does not need any storage.

Comment: @iharob Funny. I didn't know CLion had been ported from Mac to QNX.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. This is my first experience with C, I made the mistake of coding it in cLion and having it work perfectly when I should have just done it via the text document. I did not realise there would be an issue between the interpreter and when I went to gcc compile. I still have no idea why my statement is just returning the last two values of the characters that were read instead of the first 2 like it is supposed to

Comment: You have a typo here: `printf("%n");`. Probably want `printf("\n");`

Comment: Thank you, user4581301, the code works exactly as intended now, it was the typo, apparently the cLion interpreter adjusted for the %n and did a new line in its place.

Comment: @whiskeygolf It's not just *the* typo, your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: No it did not (and any tool which does should be instantly deleted). You invoked _undefined behaviour_. As you do when reading your array. Read @iharob s answer.

Comment: The code may have undefined behavior, but I am just learning C, so I will definitely work on that, but the typo does fix the issue I was having with it not compiling like I had intended it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char input_line [7] ;

int charRead = read (fp, input_line, 8 ) ;
```

Reads 8 bytes into a 7 byte array, which is bad. It just wrote over some memory after the array, but since the array is 7 bytes and most data is aligned on 4 or 8 byte values, you probably get away with it by not reading data over anything important.

But!!! Here is your data:

```
00P015<EOL>
00P116<EOL>
030000<EOL>
06P0ZZ<EOL>
030005<EOL>
...
```

On a Unix-based system where the end of line is one byte, reading 8 bytes will read

```
00P015<EOL>0
```

And the next eight bytes will read

```
0P116<EOL>03
```

etcetera... So here is your data on drugs:

```
00P015<EOL>0
0P116<EOL>03
0000<EOL>06P
0ZZ<EOL>0300
05<EOL>...
```

See what happens? Not what you need or want.

How this could work in the IDE, smurfed if I know, unless the input file is actually a windows text file (two byte end of line mark), but it's playing with fire. I'm going to stick with C and pitch [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) as an alternative to read. I also stripped out all of the stuff not essential to this example.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void) argc; // I'm being pedantic. As pointed out below in the comments, this
                 // is not needed. Main needs no arguments. I just like them.
    (void) argv;
    //Read file into VM
// moved all variables into function
    char memory [100][6] ; //This is likely program death if you read more than 100 
                           // lines from the file. There are no guards to prevent this 
                           // in the original code.
    int opcode ;
    int program_line = 0 ;


    FILE* fp ; //using a C FILE handle rather than a posix handle for maximum portability

    char input_line [8] ;// death if a line is poorly formatted and has extra characters, 
                         // but in this case, the whole program falls apart.                            
                         // Went with 8 in case the input file was formatted for Windows.

    fp = fopen("asd.txt", "r") ; // using c standard library file open
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return 0 ;
    }
    int itemsRead = fscanf(fp, "%s\n", input_line) ;
    //fscanf is a much more tractable reader. This will read one string of characters 
    // up to the end of line. It will easily and happily run past the end of input_line 
    // if the line is poorly formatted
    // handles a variety of EOL types. and returns the number of the requested 
    // items read. In this case, one item.
    printf("\n*******************************\n");
    printf("* Reading Program Into Memory *\n");
    printf("*******************************\n");
    while (itemsRead == 1 && input_line[0] != 'Z' && program_line < 100) 
    { // much better place for the exit conditions. Also added test to prevent 
      // overrunning memory
        for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
        {
            memory[program_line][i] = input_line[i] ;
        } // this can also be performed with memcpy
        printf("Program Line %d: ", program_line) ;
        for(int i = 0; i <  6; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", memory[program_line][i]) ;
        } // if we were using properly terminated c-style strings, and we are not, 
          // this loop and the following printf("\n") could be replaced with  
          // printf("%s\n", memory[program_line]). As it is putc would be a more 
          // efficient option
        printf("\n") ;

        opcode = (memory[program_line][0] -'0') *10 ;  // '0' much easier to read than 48
        opcode += memory[program_line][1] -'0' ;

        printf("Opcode is %d\n", opcode) ;

        charRead = fscanf(fp, "%s\n", input_line) ;

        program_line++ ;
        printf("\n"); // fixed typo
    }
}
```

And in C++, this sucker is trivial

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void) argc; // I'm still being pedantic.
    (void) argv;
    //Read file into VM

    std::vector<std::string> memory;
    int opcode;

    std::ifstream in("asd.txt");
    std::cout << "\n*******************************\n"
              << "* Reading Program Into Memory *\n"
              << "*******************************\n";
    std::string input_line;
    while (std::getline(in, input_line) && input_line[0] != 'Z')
    {
        memory.push_back(input_line);
        std::cout << input_line << std::endl;
        opcode = (input_line[0] - '0') * 10 + input_line[1] - '0';

        std::cout << "Opcode is " << opcode << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

A note on being pedantic. There is this wonderful compiler option called `-pedantic` It instructs the compiler to do some fairly anally retentive error checking. Add it , `-Wall`, and `-Wextra` to your command line. Together they will spot a lot of mistakes. And some stuff that isn't mistakes, but you can't win them all.

Comment: If you are pedantic remove the parameters, `int main(void)` is valid too.

Comment: Yup, but I like the arguments there. They remind me of better times. Fixed a whole bunch of glitches, though, and generally cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading `8` bytes which takes the end of line character `'\n'` and tries to store it in a `7` bytes array.

```
read (fp, input_line, 8)
```

this leads to undefined behavrio, and it should be

```
read(fp, input_line, 7)
```

And then you could just discard the next byte like

```
char discard; 
read(fp, &discard, 1);
```

I suppose you was reading `8` bytes to consume the end of line character, so you could have increased the array size to `8` and ignore the last character or simply read it and discard it.

**EDIT**: Looking closely at the data and your code, I found out that I don't understand what you try to do, you must read just `7` characters, that will include the trailing `'\n'`, the following code will work if and only if there is always a new line `'\n'` after each line, otherwise it will skip the last line, you should think of the obvious solution yourself. Also, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772630/c-program-executing-differently-from-shell/32772868#comment53384898_32772868), if you write the program with a text editor on MS Windows, you will have trouble. To solve that you can just use `fopen()` instead of low level I/O.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int file;
    ssize_t length;
    char buffer[7];
    file = open("program.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (file == -1)
        return -1;
    while ((length = read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) == 0)
    {
        int opcode;
        /* You will need to overwrite the '\n' for the printf() to work 
         * but you can skip this if you don't want to print the command
         */
        buffer[length - 1] = '\0'; 
        opcode = 10 * (buffer[0] - '0') + buffer[1] - '0';
        fprintf(stderr, "Command: `%s'\n\topcode: %d\n", buffer, opcode);
    }
    close(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem is, the text can have one or two chars as line-end (Unix/Windows/MAC style (not sure if OS-X still uses CR as end-of-line char). OP should better use a proper line-reader.

Comment: @Olaf, absolutely true, quick solution would be to use `fopen()`.

Comment: IIRC (I normally do not use C on PC), Linux/Unix does not differentiate between text or binary file-mode. But some editors in Linux might use Windows-CR/LF to be "compatible" with Notepad ( ... )

Comment: @Olaf I think OS X does not, only MS-DOS did and windows inherited it, I am not 100% sure, but say 75%.

Comment: Well, old MacOS did, but I'm not sure if/when they stopped, but I also think it is likely they now use proper LF-only. (or they pack every text into XML now;-)

Comment: @Olaf If any Linux editors use CR/LF, they won't be compatible with 99% of Unix utilities, which assume LF is the only line separator.

Comment: @Barmar: Where did I state they are bound to it? They just **can** use the line-ending you select and/or which the current file uses. And most Linux tools can already handle a CR (they just ignore it in textfiles). I cannot even remember I had a problem with `less` or `grep` on DOS files. Anyway, I normally don't use it (why should I add a superfluous character?) and the Windows guys have to learn to use something different than Notepad.

Comment: @Olaf Try running a shell script that has CRLF line endings.

Comment: @Olaf `grep 'string$' filename` doesn't work if the file has CRLF endings, because the `$` anchor only matches before LF, not before CRLF.

Comment: @Barmar: Hmm... you are right, bash reports an error for the CR. Interesting, thank you for increasing my knowledge! Anyway, I think you got my point. More recent GUI-Editors tolerate CR/LF and can generate such endings if you configure. I did not want to imply there is any actual use for this beyond generating files the Windows standard editor Notepad (did they finally trash this crap in Win10?) can handle properly.